# Is using comment() from base to assign information to R object slowing the code down?

Tags: r

Is using `comment()` from `base` to assign information to R object slowing the code down?

That is, should its implementation be used carefully?

Context: I'm having a function that creates several tibbles/dataframes that are saved in a list; and I'm thinking of saving a comment to each dataframe (or just saving one comment to the entire list).

Comment: The `comment` documentation states that the function sets or gets a comment attribute to any R object, hence I don't believe that using it iteratively on multiple objects will sensibly slow your code down (doing a benchmark now). How many dataframes are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `comment` documentation it seems that the method is just an interface to get/set a comment attribute to any R object. I can't see it becoming a burden in the vast majority of real-world use cases.

To have an idea of how the function behaves under load I've written a simple function to generate *n* dataframes (2000 rows, 3 columns) and annotate them at will. Results will be appended to a list:

```r
df_and_comment <- function(n, add_comment = FALSE) {
  res_list <- list()
  for (i in seq(1:n)) {
    x <- data.frame(
      x = rnorm(2000),
      y = rnorm(2000),
      z = rnorm(2000)
    )
    if (add_comment) {
      comment(x) <- sprintf("this is df no: %d", i)
    }
    res_list[[i]] <- x
  }
  res_list
}
```

### Normal load - creating 50 dataframes

```r
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  df_and_comment(n=50),
  df_and_comment(n=50, add_comment = TRUE),
  times = 10
)

Unit: milliseconds
                                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
                     df_and_comment(n = 50) 25.34398 25.51473 26.70731 25.74472 25.97483 33.81251    10
 df_and_comment(n = 50, add_comment = TRUE) 26.32009 26.39826 27.49835 26.60218 27.80038 32.47273    10
```

### Heavy load - creating 15.000 dataframes

```r
microbenchmark(
  df_and_comment(n=15000),
  df_and_comment(n=15000, add_comment = TRUE),
  times = 10
)

Unit: seconds                                          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
                     df_and_comment(n = 15000) 8.218535 8.254919 8.324075 8.317126 8.354637 8.469191    10
 df_and_comment(n = 15000, add_comment = TRUE) 8.414405 8.561279 8.687380 8.571137 8.685309 9.591972    10
```

---

In both cases, the performance difference are completely negligible. I wouldn't be worried about performance implications of annotating dataframes/regression results iteratively.